# Get image src using scrapy python

Tags: python, scrapy

I have following issue:

I want to scrape the src from a image using scrapy. Is it possible to do this in python (scrapy) like in javascript?

For instance:

```
<img class="test image_of_something" src="some_url">
```

The output should be "some_url". first problem: Somehow with

```
response.css("img")
```

i dont get all img-classes from the website. And is it possible to use some kind of queryselector? Since i want only specific image src. Like in javascript

```
document.querySelector(".image_of_something").src
```

i want to do this in pyhton. So far i stuck in my scrapy documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First navigate to img element that contains your deisred class, then select the `@src` attribute.

Like this:

```
 image_url = response.xpath('//img[contains(@class,"image_of_something")]/@src').extract()[0]
```

Comment: Somehow the response is empty. OK lets try with a random example. Lets say i want to scrape the first image post of linkedin account of volkswagen. Lets say

https://de.linkedin.com/company/volkswagen-ag

And the image i want has the image class

    <img class=mini-card__image share-article__image lazy-loaded ....>

Somehow if i type your example i cant scrape it. any ideas?

Comment: LinkedIn pages are not being rendered by the server side, it is being rendered using some JS framework, that's why you see an empty response, search for how to scrape a JS loaded page. @kxell2001